# Nuances of meaning between "dürfen" and "sollen" as "Annahme" auxiliary verbs

Tags: meaning

> Das **dürfte** kein Problem sein.
>
> {vs}:Das **sollte** kein Problem sein.

When the auxiliary verbs *dürfen* and *sollen* are used for the
*Vermutung / Annahme* sense, I wonder if there are nuances of meaning between the two.

I suppose *sollen* can be either in Indicative or in Konjunctive, while *dürfen* can only be in Konjunctive, when they are used to indicate an informed guess?

On another note: Does the Konjunctive *sollte* suggest that the speaker is somewhat less certain than when the Indicative *soll* is used?

Comment: For a great number of verbs, Konjunktiv II is not distinguishable from Indikativ in the Präteritum tense. That's what you are stumbling over here. For *dürfen* the forms are *durfte* vs. *dürfte*, while for *sollen* both forms are *sollte*. There is no deeper meaning behind this. You can use both verbs in Indikativ or Konjunktiv II.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure about the subject, but das dürfte kein Problem sein.

however

> I have done this often and from my experience sollte das kein Problem
>   sein.

One is more of a hunch, maybe based on second hand knowledge. Where the second is more solid based on first hand knowledge. But still would require a formal verification in order to say. Das ist kein Problem.

Answer (score 0):

About your first and main question:

No, there aren't any differences in meaning between the conjunctive forms of *sollen* and *müssen* in your sentences. You can use them interchangeably here.

---

About your second question:

> **Conjunctive:** Das **sollte** kein Problem sein. *This **shouldn't** be a problem.*
>   **Indicative:** Das **soll** kein Problem sein. *This **shall not** be a problem.*

The indicative version of this sentence is not wrong, but pretty uncommon, and it also implies that the speaker is going to make sure there won't be any problem; hence, it's less of a prediction, but rather a mild form of promise.

Answer (score -1):

> *Das* **dürfte** *kein Problem sein*
>
> *Das* **sollte** *kein Problem sein*

These two should only be used in Conjunctive. Otherwise, they sound weird and more like a command.

Besides, I would recommend using dürfen instead of sollen because sollen doesn't sound like you are assuming something.